# What's the name of the highest level of Cold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages on [Cold](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Cold) says:

> If you reach the highest level of Cold, your health will be reduced to zero and you will die from exposure to the elements.

But what is that "highest level"? It seems that "Numb" is the highest *named* level, given the table at the bottom of the page, but presumably that's still survivable, otherwise its effects wouldn't matter because it'd be death?

But apparently, since if you can die from the cold, there's different internally coded stages of being Numb, and the last one is lethal?

Comment: Frostbite comes to mind, but not sure if it’s the term Skyrim uses

Comment: @Wondercricket - Frostbitten's a status condition, but it's not lethal: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Disease#Frostbitten

Comment: *Frostfall* calls it, "You are freezing to death." There's no name, there's a bar. And when that bar runs out you fall over. Depending on your settings, it's either fatal or you are rescued. I highly doubt that that CC addition holds a candle to Frostfall, but I wouldn't know because I've boycotted CC on principle. - "there's different internally coded stages of being Numb" - No, 'numb' is 800-1000. Reach 1000 and there's no room for health and you die. Same prob with radiation in Fallout. "your health will be reduced to zero and you will die [because that's how HP works]". It's not a 'status'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple misunderstanding of the word "level." By "the highest level of cold," the wiki simply means "1000 cold or more." It does not correspond to any of the named "levels."

Another way to think about it: The more cold you are, the more your maximum health is reduced. When your maximum health reaches zero (which happens at 1000 cold), you die.